# How can I use log4j on remote Tomcat container

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j

I have a simple J2ee application and I use log4j to logger the information.

This is the file log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="ROOT_APPENDER" class="capacita.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="C:/logs/err_pcs.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="50MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="capacita.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} | %X{serverInstance} | %p | %X{sessionId} | %C{1} | %M | %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ERROR_APPENDER" class="capacita.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="C:/logs/err_pcs.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="50MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="capacita.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} | %X{serverInstance} | %p | %X{sessionId} | %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOGIN_APPENDER" class="com.springmvcapp.log.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="C:/logs/login-pcs.log"/>
        <rollingPolicy class="com.springmvcapp.log.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="fileNamePattern" value="@log4j.logs@/log-pcs-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log"/>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="capacita.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}|%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE_APPENDER" class="capacita.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="capacita.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{HH:mm:ss}] [%p] [%C{1}].[%M](%L) %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROOT_APPENDER"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="ERROR">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_APPENDER"/>
        <!--appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER"/-->
    </logger>

    <logger name="ROOT">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ROOT_APPENDER"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER"/>
        <!--appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER"/ -->
    </logger>

    <logger name="LOGIN">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LOGIN_APPENDER"/>
        <!--appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER"/-->
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

So, when I try to run this application in my local PC, I retrieve this file under
C:/logs and it is ok.
Now when I try to run this application into hosting container. (Linux) I don't find this file. Before start the tomcat in remote container, I have removed C:/, but I don't find these file.
How can I fixed this problem.

EDIT:
In the Tomcat's log I have this message:

```
log4j:INFO Using URL [file:/E:/PROGRA~1/APACHE~1/TOMCAT~1.34/instances/tomcat7.0.34_1405/webapps/spring_mvc/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration of repository named [default].
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem. I have insert this code to create the log file

```
<param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/err_pcs.log"/>
```